# boundary of radius when transforming into polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose there is a ellipse whose semi-axis is $a$ and $b$.

I want to double integrate some function over this region.

So, I am trying to transform into polar coordinates.

I think boundary of angle should be from $0$ to $2\pi$. What is the boundary of $r$ then?

Comment: It is : $0<= r <=1$.

Comment: independent of semi-axis?

Comment: Yes. The parametrization is $(arcos(\theta),brsin(\theta))$.